# ADO.NET working with SQL and database

Tags: ado.net

I'm getting an exception error saying missing operators can anyone help

```
string sql = "Select SalesPerson.Name, Item.Description, Orders.Quantity, Orders.OrderDate"
                + "From([Orders]"
                + "Inner Join[SalesPerson] On Orders.SalesPersonID=SalesPerson.SalesPersonID)"
                + "Inner Join[Item] On Orders.ItemNumber=Item.ItemNumber"
                + "Where Orders.CustomerID=@customer Order by Orders.OrderDate DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **some spaces** at the end of each of your lines of SQL!

```
string sql = "SELECT SalesPerson.Name, Item.Description, Orders.Quantity, Orders.OrderDate "
                + "FROM [Orders] "
                + "INNER JOIN [SalesPerson] ON Orders.SalesPersonID = SalesPerson.SalesPersonID "
                + "INNER JOIN [Item] ON Orders.ItemNumber = Item.ItemNumber "
                + "WHERE Orders.CustomerID = @customer " 
                + "ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate DESC";
```

Otherwise, your SQL ends up being

```
Select ..... Orders.OrderDateFROM([Orders]Inner Join[SalesPerson] .....
```

and so on - and that's just ***not*** valid SQL.

I also removed some unnecessary parenthesis around the `JOIN` operators - those are only needed for MS Access, but since you're saying you're using ADO.NET, I assume this is *not* for MS Access and therefore, those parenthesis are not needed